# Salesforce Custom Button Ajax Loader

Tags: visualforce

I want to show loading gif image when salesforce custom button(javascript detail button) is clicked.Is there any way by which we can do this?or is there any event like Onwait or so in which we can load the gif image to prevent the user from further action until the processing is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<apex:actionStatus>` or `Jquery` UI block/unblock

E.g. Below is just a code snippet that can work for you.

```
<apex:actionStatus id="pageStatus">
    <apex:facet name="start">
        <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.25; z-index: 1000; background-color: black;">
                    &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 20px; z-index: 1001; margin: 15% 50%">
        <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px; background-color: #fff; width: 125px;">
            <img src="/img/loading.gif" style="float: left; margin: 8px;" />
            <span style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0px;">Please Wait...</span>
        </div>
        </div>            
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>

<apex:commandButton action="{!sav}" status="pageStatus" value="Save" />
```

Comment: It is not a command button.It is a custom button created on an object level.

Comment: You mean to say custom button that is added on the Standard Page layout